# How to make glyphicons or image align right in sidenav

Tags: html, css

how could I make pictures or glyphicons to sit on the right side all the time regardless of the length of the text? in the current form if the text on the left side is enlarged the alignment is lost. I tried with align="right" but it doesn't work, any ideas?

```css
#mySidenav a {
  position: fixed;
  left: -145px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 180px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

#mySidenav a:hover {
  left: 0;
}

#about {
  top: 80px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

#blog {
  top: 140px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

#projects {
  top: 200px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

#contact {
  top: 260px;
  background-color: #555
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#" id="about">Money: 500 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&euro;</a>
  <a href="#" id="blog">test: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell" align="right"></span></a>
  <a href="#" id="projects">test</a>
  <a href="#" id="contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean up `&nbsp;` and just use `.glyphicon` class on an icon like $euro and css to float right

```css
#mySidenav a {
  position: fixed;
  left: -145px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 180px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

#mySidenav a:hover {
  left: 0;
}

#about {
  top: 80px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

#blog {
  top: 140px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

#projects {
  top: 200px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

#contact {
  top: 260px;
  background-color: #555
}

.glyphicon {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#" id="about">Money: 500 <span class="glyphicon">&euro;</span></a>
  <a href="#" id="blog">test: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span></a>
  <a href="#" id="projects">testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest</a>
  <a href="#" id="contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```